# What is the fastest way to do this string patten substitution in python?

Tags: python

Given a string in patten

```
str="a@b = c"
```

want to substitute it to

```
str="a@'b'"
```

Namely, quote 'b' and remove any thing following " = " and itself.

What is the optimal way to do this in python?

EDIT:

'b' above can be any unknown non-whitespace string in any length

Comment: Regex.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Just use a regular expression. It will be 'fastest' and 'optimal' enough. And *if* not, you'll have need to construct a performance benchmark (hopefully one that is holistic of the problem). But really, there is no need even think about such things before 'working'.

Comment: I think that you may want to detail a bit more about your pattern.  For example Pabtorre's answer is correct, but applies only to **this** string.  Is that what you are looking for?  Is it always a 'b' after the '@'?  If not, is it only 1 character after the @ and before the = ?  Or is a@bxyz = ... possible?

Comment: @JLPeyret Yes, indeed b can be any string "bxyz..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"%s@'%s'"%tuple(txt.split(' =')[0].split('@'))
```

This one works with any arbitrary value for a or b as long as they're separated by '@' and c is separated by '='.

PS. It breaks if b contains ' =' or '@'

Edit: Adding a speed benchmark, based on Green Cell's.

edit_again: adding other examples to the benchmark.

```
import re

import timeit

# Method #1 (string ops) -> Green Cell's
def stringOps():
    s="a@whammy = c"
    replaceChar = s.split('@')[1].split(' ')[0] 
    s.split('=')[0].replace(replaceChar, "'{0}'".format(replaceChar) ).replace(' ', '')
time1 = timeit.timeit('from __main__ import stringOps;stringOps()')
# Method #2 (regex)  -> Dawg's 
def regex():
    s="a@bam = c"
    re.sub(r'(\w+)(\s*=\s*\w+$)', r"'\1'", s)


time2 = timeit.timeit('from __main__ import regex;regex()')

#%method 3 split_n_dice  -> my own
def slice_dice():
    txt="a@whammy = c"
    "%s@'%s'"%tuple(txt.split(' =')[0].split('@'))

time3 = timeit.timeit('from __main__ import slice_dice;slice_dice()')    

print 'Method #1 took {0}'.format(time1)
print 'Method #2 took {0}'.format(time2)
print 'Method #3 took {0}'.format(time3)
```

> > > Method #1 took 2.01555299759
> > >
> > > Method #2 took 4.66884493828
> > >
> > > Method #3 took 1.44083309174

Comment: Given the lack of more info in the question, ^ agreed :)

Comment: Slice 'n' dice looks more readable too. Looks like we have a winner

Comment: funny thing... I ran the benchmarks again on python3... and they all run slower :O 

I wonder why that is. 
Python3: 
>>> Method #1 took 3.001633934999518
>>> Method #2 took 6.020679088999714
>>> Method #3 took 2.2396436239996547

Python2: 
>>> Method #1 took 2.01555299759
>>> Method #2 took 4.66884493828
>>> Method #3 took 1.44083309174

Answer (score 3):

Updating example. Assuming the character we want to replace is always proceeding '@':

```
str="a@b = c"
replaceChar = str.split('@')[1].split(' ')[0] 
print str.split('=')[0].replace(replaceChar, "'{0}'".format(replaceChar) ).replace(' ', '')
```

Outputs:

```
a@'b'
```

Running the same code on the follow:

```
str="a@e = c"
str="a@test = c"
str="a@whammy = c"
```

Outputs:

```
a@'e'
a@'test'
a@'whammy'
```

Is this what you're after?

**Update**

Since someone finally provided a method with regex, we can benchmark them.

```
import re
import timeit

# Method #1 (string ops)
def stringOps():
    s="a@whammy = c"
    replaceChar = s.split('@')[1].split(' ')[0] 
    s.split('=')[0].replace(replaceChar, "'{0}'".format(replaceChar) ).replace(' ', '')

# Method #2 (regex)
def regex():
    s="a@bam = c"
    re.sub(r'(\w+)(\s*=\s*\w+$)', r"'\1'", s)

timestamp1 = timeit.Timer('from __main__ import stringOps;stringOps()')
timestamp2 = timeit.Timer('from __main__ import regex;regex()')
iterations = 1000000
time1 = timestamp1.timeit(iterations)
time2 = timestamp2.timeit(iterations)
print 'Method #1 took {0}'.format(time1)
print 'Method #2 took {0}'.format(time2)
```

Output:

```
Method #1 took 4.98833298683
Method #2 took 14.708286047
```

So it appears that regular expressions are still slower in this case. Although I'll give them credit, is feeling more readable. If you're not doing any crazy iterations I would just do the method you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: And poof / reasoning that this is 'faster' (or more 'optimal' how)?  I find this very convoluted and hard to read; thus, without justification, I cannot condone such.

Comment: In general I always try to avoid the use of regular expressions until it becomes reasonable to use them. This is fairly straight forward with string operations, and anyone who codes with python knows what's going on here. Do show your solution if you think this isn't measuring up.

Comment: It's often the case string operation is preferable compared to regex.

Comment: and some people don't like/care for regular expressions.  and that should be their choice, no?  the OP can decide which one to use and you can always post your own answer, no?  for me, I find that simple string functions are usually faster, but I could be wrong without benchmarking.  and yes, I do use regular expressions when I feel it warranted.

Comment: @JLPeyret regardless of what "some people" like or not, regular expressions are a **required** part of general programming. There are some tasks that are too difficult or simply impossible to perform using string operations alone. For example, find two digits followed by one or more spaces/tabs/newlines followed by three capital letters. *Possible* to do with string ops (maybe), but a short 1-liner with regex.

Comment: I don't disagree.  Regex are a tool.  Sometimes they are a really good fit.  Sometimes they are not, or simpler string manipulations perform as well.  If user2... had posted a regex answer, I would not have criticized it.  I don't see why he has to rag on someone's else's answer without reason.  And sometimes, especially for people not fluent in them, simple one liner regular expressions are PERL-like.  Code once, never understand again.

Comment: I updated the question. 'b' can be anything. It is unknown.

Comment: Put it in a function and use [```timeit.Timer```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) to test it.

Comment: A GreenCell - good benchmarking.  I did recall that regex can be slower, but nice to see a quantified comparison.

Comment: ^ Thanks, it's nice to see a comparison :)
@wwii - Updated

Comment: Yes, for my answer and a regex, as I originally said I try to avoid them since they tend to be slower. Now stop being lazy and bench mark your own ;)

Comment: regex are generally slower than string operations, since they perform several extra steps. 
I added more benchmarks (based on your test) on my own answer. :)

Comment: funny thing... I ran the benchmarks again on python3... and they all run slower :O 

I wonder why that is. 
Python3: 
>>> Method #1 took 3.001633934999518
>>> Method #2 took 6.020679088999714
>>> Method #3 took 2.2396436239996547

Python2: 
>>> Method #1 took 2.01555299759
>>> Method #2 took 4.66884493828
>>> Method #3 took 1.44083309174

Answer (score 1):

Since you state that *'b' above can be any unknown non-whitespace string in any length* the best is probably a regex.

This regex performs the replacement:

```
/(\w+)(\s*=\s*\w+$)/'\1'/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iK3rU3/1)

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s="a@b = c"
>>> re.sub(r'(\w+)(\s*=\s*\w+$)', r"'\1'", s)
"a@'b'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will be the fastest or most efficient but it is pretty simple.

Relies on the `@` and `=` being *constants* in the string and only one of each.

```
s = "a@b = c"
keep, _ = s.split('=')
keep = keep.strip()
keep = keep.split('@')
keep[1] = "\'" + keep[1] + "\'"
#keep[1] = r"'" + keep[1] + r"'"
#keep[1] = "'" + keep[1] + "'"
result = '@'.join(keep)
```

---

As a function:

```
def f(s):
    keep, _ = s.split('=')
    keep = keep.strip()
    keep = keep.split('@')
    keep[1] = "\'" + keep[1] + "\'"
    return '@'.join(keep)
```